# How android lollipop is drawing images and what is "prepare" stage in gpu profiler

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm developing an app. This app has an layout. The layout is fairly simple. To make it even simpler, let's say that the layout consists of TextView and CustomView. The purpose of this custom view is drawing a large bitmap (1080 x 700).

In CustomView I store an integer for image resource. In its constructor I'm executing an AsyncTask to start decompressing resource. When decompressing finishes the CustomView is invalidated. In draw method I'm checking if bitmap hasn't already been decompressed then it does nothing, if bitmap is decompressed then the CustomView is drawing it and freeing it resources.

So far so good :)

I have test devices:
1. ZTE blade III - 1GHz single core, 512MB RAM, running android 4.0.4 (API 15)
2. HTC Desire X - 1GHz single core, 1GB RAM, running android 4.1.1 (API 16)
3. HTC Sensation 1.5 GHz dual core, 768MB RAM, running android 4.4.4 (API 19, rooted)
4. Google Nexus 5, 2.27GHZ quad-core, 2GB RAM, running android 5.0.1 (API 21)

At the time of developing I was testing on device 1, because it should be the slowest and if there everything is OK, so it would be OK everywhere else. And yes the approach from above worked well on this device.

Then I tried to device 2 - everything was as expected.

Then device 3 - again everything is good. On this device I run "Profile GPU rendering" to see how good it really is. Most of the time the bars are below green line, just when the bitmap is showing on the screen, they are higher and dropping fps from 60+ to around 30, which is good again. First of all I thought that canvas.drawBitmap() is slow, but when I check it the results was - less than 1ms for executing canvas.drawBitmap(). I checked again bars from "Profile GPU rendering". The blue and orange onces were low and yellow was above green line. Then I checked what does these colors mean http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html. The yellow one is for "waiting commands to complete" - so everything looks good.

On 4th device I was expecting the best performance, but....no. Here the entire UI thread is freezing when the bitmap have to be shown on screen. I run again "Profile GPU rendering". Here for my great surprise are 4 colors. The 3 from above and purple one. At the time when bitmap is shown on the screen and UI thread freezes exactly the purple bar is from bottom to top of the screen so I see only tiny blue and HUGE purple bar. I try to see what is that bar for and found that is mean "prepare" -  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89017/what-does-purple-colour-mean-in-gpu-rendering-profiling.

So finally my question is what am I missing for drawing bitmaps for lollipop and why this prepare stage takes so long when drawing bitmaps? Is It connected to lollipop or to Nexus 5? It is impossible for Google to add new stage which slows down the UI pipeline

**UPDATE:**
So after a lot of testing I realized that I have missed something :)
Really stupid that I didn't realized it earlier, but.... :(

As I said the app is still under developing and because of that I am making just a single drawable and putting it inside drawable-nodpi folder. But in this case I put it in wrong folder, instead of drawable-nodpi, I put it in drawable. This was causing Nexus 5 to decode it 9 times large bitmap and this was causing slowness.